# Getting "at-rule or selector expectedts-styled-plugin(9999)" error in style component with two interpolation strings

Tags: reactjs, plugins, styled-components

I keep getting this error on styled components `at-rule or selector expectedts-styled-plugin(9999)`, I looked on the internet and can't find any fix that's not a workaround.

[image]

anyone had the same problem and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you seem to have forgotten to close the curly brace of the `&::before` clause.

Comment: you should flag this question to be closed because it uses images of code (needs debugging details).